# Get rows of max values for unique value in other column: python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter the following dataframe from the view seen in 'Initial dataframe' to what is displayed in 'Desired output'

Initial dataframe

```
name          group     subject  score   class_size
                                 
Steve       classrm_A   maths    98.22      20
John        classrm_A   maths    76.87      30
Mary        classrm_C   science  77.25      26
Steve       classrm_B   science  65.28      32
Mary        classrm_A   english  86.01      16
John        classrm_F   science  96.55      25
```

Return rows for unique 'name' values where score' is greatest and 'class_size' is equal or greater than 25.

Desired output:

```
name          group     subject  score   class_size
                                 
Steve       classrm_B   science  65.28      32
Mary        classrm_C   science  77.25      26
John        classrm_F   science  96.55      25
```

Here is what I have attempted so far.....

```
min_class = df["class_size"] >= 25


df = df["min_class "]


df = df.groupby(['name']).max('score')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: @ScottHunter Your comments are noted and I apologize for my tardy ask. I have now added my attempt which I hope you can comment on

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the logic - why do you return the row with `Mary`, where class size is 16? (You put 26 there instead, which seems to be coming from her other class)

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Although Mary has a maximum score of 86.01, that score is associated with a clas_size of less than 25. Only scores linked to 'class_size' 25 and greater are to to be considered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep only rows with class size above 25 in dataframe,
then sort dataframe by score,
then drop all duplicates of column "name" and keep only the first row in case of duplicates.

```py
df = df[df["class_size"] >= 25]
df = df.sort_values("score", ascending=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["name"], keep="first")
```

---

**Output:**

```py
Out[23]: 
    name      group  subject  score  class_size
5   John  classrm_F  science  96.55          25
2   Mary  classrm_C  science  77.25          26
3  Steve  classrm_B  science  65.28          32
```

Comment: I added a df.reset_index() to this and it outputs perfectly. Cheers mate. Combining `df.drop_duplicates` and  `subset` seems to form a hybrid version of groupby

Comment: You can also use `.sort_index()` to get your desired order. Glad I could help, if the answer helps you, could you accept it as accepted answer? This way future readers quickly find the solution and I get a few points as well. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for you. I sense it's slightly different approach, than you tried, but I dare say it's more "pythonish".

```py
res = df.loc[df['class_size'].ge(25)].copy()
res['rank'] = res.groupby('name')['score'].rank(ascending=False)
res = res.loc[res['rank'].eq(1)].drop('rank', axis=1)
```

The key here is `.rank()` function with `.groupby()` - `.rank(ascending=False)` will essentially return ranking in a descending order, `.groupby()` will make you do the ranking for each group separately.

Comment: yes this is much more pythonic. However, doesn't the use of `.copy()` tend to add greater use of memory?

Comment: Nope - it's just explicit way of creating copy. Try the code without it - at least for myself- I'm getting warning then, that I try to create implicit copy. I think that's the one of python's principles - "explicit is better than implicit" ;)

Comment: You would create copy either way - unless you would like to replace `df` as in `df = df.loc[...]` you can safely put `.copy()` at the end. It will exactly make your code more explicit

Comment: "explicit is better than implicit"  nice phrase and advice